# R: Read XML file and delete tags with specific attributes

Tags: xml, r

I have the following XML file (just a extract):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Osmosis 0.44.1">
  <node id="1" version="1" timestamp="2015-09-03T12:41:49Z" lat="11.7889317" lon="11.0905799">
    <tag k="ID_2" v="141411"/>
    <tag k="FullName" v=""/>
    <tag k="OID" v="1111"/>
    <tag k="NAME" v="name"/>
    <tag k="AdditionalInformation" v=""/>
    <tag k="id" v="1234567890"/>
    <tag k="shortname" v=""/>
    <tag k="NR" v=""/>
  </node>
  <way id="9">
        <nd ref="10"/>
        <nd ref="11"/>
        <nd ref="12"/>
        <nd ref="13"/>
    <tag k="ID_2" v=""/>
    <tag k="FullName" v="Somefullname"/>
    <tag k="OID" v="358"/>
    <tag k="NAME" v=""/>
    <tag k="AdditionalInformation" v=""/>
    <tag k="id" v="71358"/>
    <tag k="shortname" v="MUC"/>
    <tag k="NR" v="50"/>
  </way>
```

Now my previous step added all `k=` attributes to all nodes and ways. Well what i need now is to delete all tags where `v=""` appears for example:

In the node tag:

```
<tag k="shortname" v=""/>
<tag k="NR" v=""/>
```

and in the way tag:

```
<tag k="ID_2" v=""/>
<tag k="NAME" v=""/>
```

using R and the `XML package` and save everything back into the open XML file. Because the `k=` attributes can change it would be great if there is a solution where i can search the tags with `v=""` and delete those tags where it appears, not having to search for the whole tags like `<tag k="NR" v=""/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `removeNodes` and then save

```
removeNodes(doc["//node/tag[@v='']"])
removeNodes(doc["//way/tag[@v='']"])
```

Comment: O.k if you know how to do it it looks pretty simple. But well again I have to say that the documentation of the XML package is quite bad and not self explaining at all at least not for a beginner. Thank you for your answer!